# how to get mac of ethernet and wifi card in java? (only 2 card)

Tags: java

I want to get mac(for license product), but I received too many result (sorry if my English is not good):

```
    public void testGetMac() throws SocketException {
    Enumeration<NetworkInterface> interfaces = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();

    int i = 0;
    while (interfaces.hasMoreElements() && i < 3)
    {
        NetworkInterface nif = interfaces.nextElement();
        byte[] lBytes = nif.getHardwareAddress();
        StringBuffer lStringBuffer = new StringBuffer();

        if (lBytes != null)
        {
            for (byte b : lBytes)
            {
                lStringBuffer.append(String.format("%1$02X ", new Byte(b)));
            }
            i ++;
        }

        System.out.println(lStringBuffer);

    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "too many result" ? Can you explain us or show us your current output ?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I was reading MAC in my app. Hope this helps...

```
InetAddress ip = InetAddress.getLocalHost();

        Enumeration e = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();

        while (e.hasMoreElements()) {

            NetworkInterface n = (NetworkInterface) e.nextElement();
            Enumeration ee = n.getInetAddresses();
            while (ee.hasMoreElements()) {
                InetAddress i = (InetAddress) ee.nextElement();
                if (!i.isLoopbackAddress() && !i.isLinkLocalAddress()
                        && i.isSiteLocalAddress()) {
                    ip = i;
                }
            }
        }

        NetworkInterface network = NetworkInterface.getByInetAddress(ip);
        if(network == null){
            String message = "Check your internet connection!";
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, message,"Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            return false;
        }
        byte[] address = network.getHardwareAddress();
```